# Banshee "Encountered a Fatal Error" on launch

Tags: banshee

See screenshot below, these problems had been diagnosed as I open my Banshee.

[image: encountered a fatal error]

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/30185/banshee-encountered-a-fatal-error-sqlite-error-11-database-disk-image-is-malfor/30314

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This means that the SQLite database that Banshee uses to store information about your tracks and playlists is corrupt.  This can happen if your system loses power or crashes while Banshee is running.  It's usually possible to [recover from this error](http://banshee.fm/support/faq/#corrupt-db), and there's a [bug report in progress](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=621057) that would enable Banshee to automatically attempt recovery.

For more information, see my answer to a similar question: [Banshee encountered a Fatal Error (sqlite error 11: database disk image is malformed)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30185/banshee-encountered-a-fatal-error-sqlite-error-11-database-disk-image-is-malfor/30314#30314)

Comment: ok thanks for the anwers, my banshee's recovered but all the playlist & songs are gone and need to be imported again. btw, just wanna ask you, how come this such problem happens?

Comment: Hmm, if you followed the steps for recovery on the Banshee website, it should also recover your ratings, playcounts, and playlists.  You may want to check for typos, especially in the last step: `cat dump | sqlite3 banshee.db`

This problem happens because when Banshee is running, its database is open.  If Banshee closes without closing the connection to the database (which would happen if your computer crashed), the data can become corrupt, making the database unusable.

Answer (score 1):

Simply delete `banshee.db` in `~/.config/banshee-1` and start it again.